# if condition in try block always turns out true even if it shouldn´t

Tags: java

I want to manage that the command in the if condition only is displayed for the string input from the method "zutat1" is in the file "Fleisch.txt". It gets always displayed, no matter what the input in zutat1 was.

```
public String zubezut1() {
    String zz1;
    zz1 = zutat1;

    //String[] zubereitung = {"Apple","Mango","Peach","Banana","Orange","Grapes","Watermelon","Tomato"};
    //String random = (zubereitung[new Random().nextInt(zubereitung.length)]);


    try{
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Fleisch.txt"));
      String zeile = zutat1;
      if (zeile.matches(zutat1)) {
        System.out.print(zutat1 + "_in_mudgerechte_Stücke_schneiden_und_in_der_Pfanne_scharf_anbraten");
      } // end of if

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return zz1;
  }
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with being in a try block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set

```
 String zeile = zutat1;
```

and in the line immediately following you check if they match

```
if (zeile.matches(zutat1)) {
```

In this situation, they **will always match**, since you set them equal in the preceding line.

What you probably want is:

```
zutat1 = "Mango";             // Set a value to be compared
String zeile = in.readLine(); // Read a line from the file

if (zeile.matches(zutat1)) {  // Compare the read line with the value
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are basically setting `zeile` to the same string as `zutat1`!
Since they both contain (or rather point) to the same content, they will always match.

From the names of your variables I would guess that you probably want to read a line from your file and compare that with the content of `zutat1`.

You should have a look at the [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) documentation and especially at the [readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method. That should help you figure it out.

You should additionally have a look at the [string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) documentation and check whether or not `matches` is what you really want to use.

Comment: yea, you´re right, matches wasn´t what I needed, but contains. Now it works.